# WebDriverError: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event

Tags: typescript, protractor, webdriver

I get **WebDriverError: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event** when running protractor tests with Typescript and Cucumber.

I get this error only for the 1st scenario and other scenarios works perfectly fine. I read about this error in other threads but raising it again here because the solution given in those threads didn't resolve my issue.

**Please note I never tried to open the devtools when protractor tests were running.**

Below is dependency details:

```
"@types/cucumber": "^6.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
"@types/node": "^13.1.6",
"chai": "^4.2.0",
"chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
"cucumber": "^6.0.5",
"cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.1.0",
"jasmine": "^3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"oracledb": "^4.1.0",
"protractor": "^5.4.2",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.2.0",
"protractor-html-reporter-2": "^1.0.4",
"ts-node": "^8.6.0",
"typescript": "3.6.2"
```

Config file: "conf.ts"

```
import { Config } from "protractor";
import * as reporter from "cucumber-html-reporter";
export let config: Config = {
  directConnect: true,
  framework: "custom",
  frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200/",
  capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome"
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json') // Relative path of tsconfig.json file 
    })
  },
  onComplete: () => {
    let options = {
      theme: "bootstrap",
      jsonFile: './TestReport.json',
      output: './TestReport.html',
      reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
      scenarioTimestamp: true,
      launchReport: true
    };
    reporter.generate(options);
  },
  specs: ["../features/*.feature"],
  cucumberOpts: {
    // require step definitions
    require: ["./stepdefinitions/*.js"],
    format: "json:TestReport.json"
  },
  noGlobals: true
};
```

Error Log:

```
WebDriverError: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=77.0.3865.10 (bc3579f611bbc73331171afe020ec7a45e6ccc55-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#93}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
From: Task: Protractor.get(http://localhost:4200/) - reset url
    at Driver.schedule (C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
    at ProtractorBrowser.executeScriptWithDescription (C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:404:28)
    at C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:679:25
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
    at C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27
    at C:\Users\r0m01iu\Source\Repos\MERCHSPACE\PG_Flow_Angular8\projects\mod-pg-flow\src\test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```